# VBA Code not going to next sheet to send email from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code that creates multiple sheets based on value of a column, then copies the content of each sheet in the email body for sending to intended recipients of each sheet. However, the code works only till the first sheet and does not continue to the next sheet. Can someone point out to me where exactly what I did wrong in this code? Your assistance will be highly appreciated. I am quoting the full code including functions to avoid any confusion.

```
Sub Queries_Not_Replied()

    Cells.Select
    Cells.Unmerge
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
    With selection
         .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
         .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
         .Orientation = 0
         .AddIndent = False
         .ShrinkToFit = False
         .ReadingOrder = xlLTR
    End With

    rows("1:5").Select
    selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("I").Select
    selection.Delete
    Columns("L").Select
    selection.Delete

    Cells.Select
        With selection.Borders
             .LineStyle = xlContinuous
             .Weight = xlThin
             .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Columns("M").Select
    selection.Delete

    parse_data

'Remove Original Sheet
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete

Dim email As String
email = ActiveSheet.Range("M2").Value

Dim rng As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

Set rng = Nothing
' Only send the visible cells in the selection.

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A:M" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
               vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

 Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

 With OutMail
     .To = email
     '.CC = Area Manager
     .Subject = "Queries From Banks Not Acted by your branch " &   ActiveSheet.Name
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Display
    '.Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0


    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Next sh
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

 End Sub

Private Function parse_data()
   'Created and Modified Based on extendoffice.com code
   'How to split data into multiple worksheets based on column in Excel
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer
    vcol = 11

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1:L1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
    For i = 2 To lr

       On Error Resume Next

       If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0         
       Then
            ws.Cells(ws.rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
      End If
      Next

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
   ws.Columns(icol).Clear
       For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
          ws.Range(title).AutoFilter Field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""

          If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
               Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
          Else
                 Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move       After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
          End If

ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit

 'obtain email address
Dim mTxt As String
Count = 2
While Trim(Range("K" + Trim(Count)).Value) <> ""
        Select Case Trim(Range("K" + Trim(Count)).Value)
        Case "ABA"
            mTxt = "boy@gmail.com"
        Case "ADH"
            mTxt = "tothem@yahoo.com"
        Case "AIN"
            mTxt = "someone@yahoo.com"
        Case "AMB"
            mTxt = "somebody@gmail.com"
        Case "GMB"
            mTxt = "anybody@hotmail.com"
        End Select

    If Trim(Range("K" + Trim(Count)).Value) <> "" Then
        Range("M" + Trim(Count)).Value = mTxt
    Else
        Range("M" + Trim(Count)).Value = ""
    End If

    Count = Count + 1
    Wend

    Next
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate

End Function

Private Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    ' By Ron de Bruin.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to paste the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
  End With

   'Publish the sheet to a htm file
     With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     FileName:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
  End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

  'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: There is no way your code runs without getting a run-time error. This line `Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A:M" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` can't work, for once, `("A:M" & lastRow)` is not the valid , maybe you meant to use  `("A1:M" & lastRow)`. Also, **nowhere in your code** you have `lastRow` defined or `Set`.

Comment: @shai, well the code runs without any error and captures exactly the details up to the last row of the first sheet. Nevertheless, I have modified the loop and this is now working properly. thanks for your interest in helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A:M" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 
this line should be 
Set rng = sh.Range("A:M" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it still did not go to the next sheet and this time the email body content is one row of blank columns

Comment: Assign the value to 'ThisWorkbook' and 'Dim email As String
email = ActiveSheet.Range("M2").Value' move this in For each loop. and replace sh wherever there is active sheet.

Comment: I tried making the changes as per your suggestion, but somehow it is not working. Can you try to show me exactly the changes you do? Perhaps I am doing it all wrong. Thanks again for taking your time to assist me on my problem.